# Why does this form think it should route to index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, partials, acts-as-commentable

I have a simple_form_for new_comment that results in a `undefined method`comments_path'` error in the browser, when I simply try to view the form (not submit)

**_form.html.slim**

`= simple_form_for new_comment, :remote => true do |f|`

This is in a partial, so the local variable passed is from the show page of hacks scaffold

**show.html.slim - hacks**

```
= render partial: "comments/form", locals: { new_comment: @new_comment } if user_signed_in?
```

I define @new_comment in the hacks controller

**hacks_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    @hack = Hack.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @hack.comment_threads.order('created_at DESC')
    @new_comment = Comment.build_from(@hack, current_user.id, "") if user_signed_in?
                           #build_from is a method provided by the acts_as_commentable_with_threading gem
  end
```

Why would new_comment want to route to comments_path? I'm not even submitting the form.

**routes.rb**

```
  root 'hacks#index'

  concern :commentable do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
  end

  resources :hacks, concerns: [:commentable]
  resources :users

  devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registration]
  devise_for :user,  :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", 
                                                  :sign_out => "logout", 
                                                  :sign_up => "register", 
                                                  :account_update => "account-settings" }
```

Comment: what is in your routes file?

Comment: @IS04 updated with routes. I tried changing it to `resources :hacks do resources :comments, only: [:create, :update, :destroy] end` but it still results in the same error. restarted server too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Routes**

Firstly, I don't believe your form will be routing to the `index` action

The call to `comments_path` is dependent on the CRUD actions you have defined in your routes. Specifically, `form_for` will automatically populate for the `create` action, which Rails will attempt to call from the set of `resource` based routes you'll have defined in your `routes.rb` file:

[image]

Notice from the example above, how it will go to `/photos` using the `POST` verb? This may appear to 
be sending to the "index" action (`photos_path`) - but actually, by virtue of the HTTP Verb, it will be going to the `create` action

---

**Form**

`simple_form_for` is a basically an abstraction of [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html):

> In the examples just shown, although not indicated explicitly, we
>   still need to use the :url option in order to specify where the form
>   is going to be sent. However, further simplification is possible if
>   the record passed to form_for is a resource, i.e. it corresponds to a
>   set of RESTful routes, e.g. defined using the resources method in
>   config/routes.rb. In this case Rails will simply infer the appropriate
>   URL from the record itself

Basically, `form_for` attempts to build the `url` to submit to from the objects it has. You have a nested route, which means you need to provide nested objects:

```
= simple_form_for [hack, new_comment], :remote => true do |f|
```

This should send the path to `hacks_comments_path`, which is what you want, right? Alternatively, you can stipulate the `url` option:

```
= simple_form_for new_comment, remote: true, url: hacks_comments_path(hack) do |f|
```

Notice how both of these fixes require the `hack` local variable?

```
= render partial: "comments/form", locals: { new_comment: @new_comment, hack: @hack } if user_signed_in?
```

---

**Fix**

You need to pass your `nested` path to the `simple_form_for` helper (as detailed above)

Comment: Is the choice of paths being signed to actions in order, regardless of what actions you omit a feature of rails, or is it an artifact? If you omit some actions in the types for a resource, the result is based on something like a loop through an array pg path names, rather than matched based on a hash than smartly matches helpers to actions consistently. It seems it would seem like it wouldn't be hard to change it so it does it smartly.

Answer (score 1):

Since your comments are nested within hacks, you need both the comment and the hack. So, try this

**show.html.slim**

```
= render partial: "comments/form", locals: { new_comment: @new_comment, hack: @hack } if user_signed_in?
```

**_form.html.slim**

```
= simple_form_for [hack, new_comment], :remote => true do |f|
```

Comment: I remember struggling with this before. It's only coming back to me after seeing your answer. Thank you.